# Appeal of the closure of a question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

Would you have a look at this [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/169997/when-can-we-expect-the-next-version-of-cc12#comment326196_169997) and see if it was rightfully closed?

I believe I followed all rules this time and I also got answers in the comments. While I should have received those as answers not comments, this is due to the question being closed.

If the question indeed needed to be closed, then please tell me what is wrong with it so that it doesn't happen again.

Answer (score 11):

The question was rightfully closed.

It is composed of several different questions that are:

- Vague
- Not answerable
- Speculative

These are all not good attributes for a question on the Stack Exchange site.

In particular they are of the `Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site` as the [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) discusses.

Comment: I couldn't have put it better myself.

Comment: I didn't think the question was that vague, but they were all speculative. C++ is a standard governed by the ISO. Since we aren't the ISO, anything we can say is just guesses or discussion. Especially consider the late changes to the C++11 spec before it came out.

Comment: Thanks alot.I thought accumulating questions like this that are common in sense will avoid excessive questions with close relation and thus its better.Apart from that I really dont think it was not answerable.I probably didn't make it so to limit its scope but they were indeed answerable I do really consider all the given comments as answers since they literally answered and addressed my questions in the correct way.
Thanks to them I know know how these stuff works except for the date.